# How can I use @Html.DisplayFor without using foreach loop

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a project where I want to display the details of user and then in a table I want to show the courses done by that user. When I try to display user details, the details of that user is shown as many number of courses they are taking since I am using a foreach loop. How can I do it without using foreach? I can do it if all the data is stored and retrieved from a single table but in this project I am using three tables- User, Course and UserCourse. UserCourse has foreign key reference to both UserId and CourseId. Now I want to retrieve details from user table.

**HomeController:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (DetailsEntities dc = new DetailsEntities())
        {
            var v = dc.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(u.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                Session["User"] = v;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Course");
            }
        }
    }
    return View(u);
}
```

**CourseController:**

```
public class CourseController : Controller
{
    private DetailsEntities db = new DetailsEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Course/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User user = (User)Session["User"];
        //var usr = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
        //int userId = (int)Session["UserId"];
        var user1 = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId==user.UserId);
        if (Session["User"] != null)
        {

            var course = db.UserCourses.Where(u => u.UserId == user1.UserId);
            if (user1 != null)

                return View(course);
        }
        return View(user1);
    }
}
```

**Index:**

```
<table border="1" align="center" height ="200px" width ="100%"  @*style ="background-color: darkgray"*@>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.PhoneNo)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.PhoneNo)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>   
<table border="1" align="left" height ="200px" width ="300px" @*style ="background-color: darkgray"*@>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Course.CourseName)
        </th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.CourseName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I know the question is silly but I am new at this so please help me.

Comment: What's wrong with foreach? How else would you like to display a list of records? Btw, the way you use session to store user info is considered a bad practice. You definitely need to switch to at least old Forms Authentication, not to mention newer autentication approaches.

Comment: When a user logs in I want to display that users details only once. Since I am using foreach if I have two courses then the users details are displayed twice.

Comment: Why don't you then just select a single record and pass it, rather than selecting a list and passing a list? From the way you described the problem, I can't really figure out what is the real issue.

Comment: @WiktorZychla A user can have multiple courses. So when a particular user logs in that user should view his details such as name, address etc once and he should be able to view all his courses. I have updated my latest code which also shows user deails multiple times for multiple courses.